# Query with MAX(time) doesn't return int

Tags: joomla-4.x

I have the following query on Mariadb 10.4.x with Php 8.1, the issue is that the loadResult() doesn't return int :

```
$query = $this->_db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('MAX(time)')
     ->from($this->_db->quoteName('#__mycomponent_messages'))
     ->where($this->_db->quoteName('ip') . ' = ' . $this->_db->quote($this->ip));

$lastPostTime = (int) $this->_db->loadResult();
```

By checking with phpmyadmin, it's get he time. Above the code just return 0, if i do like that :

```
$lastPostTime = $this->_db->loadResult();
```

The result is weird with

> string 'B)'

The table #__mycomponent_messages looks like that :

| id | ip | time |

|:---- |:------:| -----:|

| int (11)  | varchar(128)    | int (11) |

What's it behave like that ?

Comment: Missing `$this->_db->setQuery($query)`...

Comment: yes you are right. thanks